# i cannot install eclipse plugin for openframeworks?

Tags: 14.04, eclipse, opencv, eclipse-cdt

I tried installing it from "help -> install new software", but I'm getting an error. I have eclipse-cdt and it shows this error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.linuxtools, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,cc.openframeworks.feature,0.1.0.201510241915.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6063716986489846376.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile6063716986489846376.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,cc.openframeworks.plugin,0.1.0.201510241915.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile5346191793835378292.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile5346191793835378292.jar
```

Comment: i have eclipse helios

Answer (score 0):

Delete the artifacts.xml file in Eclipse root directory and then restart Eclipse. It will fix the problem. This works find in Eclipse Luna.

Comment: still shows the error....